# Metaflow explanation on how GPU is utilized

Tags: amazon-web-services, gpu, aws-batch, netflix-metaflow

## Objective

Understand how GPU will be utilized in Metaflow.

## Background

As in [Documentation / Explanation on how to use GPU #250](https://github.com/Netflix/metaflow/issues/250), there are several discussions on how to use GPU.

It looks `@resources(GPU=2)` looks after the GPU allocation, but there are some discussions stating AWS EC2 instance type with GPU such as P or G instances, also the type of AMI.

In my understanding, Metaflow uses AWS batch which uses ECS/Docker. Then the docker instances need GPU drivers inside docker containers ([NVIDIA Container Toolkit](https://github.com/NVIDIA/nvidia-docker)) to be able to access GPU.

Hence it is not clear how Metaflow manages the GPU and what are the prerequisites, configurations and coding required to be able to use GPU.

## Questions

1. Do we need to use a specific AMI in which GPU drivers have been pre-configured in the EC2 instance (docker host) level?
2. Do we need to use a specific EC2 type with GPU (P3, P4, G3, G4, INF1)? Or does Metaflow uses a service e.g. AWS Elastic Inference to dynamically allocate GPU even if the Batch/ECS EC2 instances do not have GPU?
3. Does Metaflow looks after installing GPU drivers inside a docker container or uses NVIDIA Container Toolkit internally?
4. Does @resource is all we need in the Python code to utilize GPU?

Answer (score 1):

To use GPU in Metaflow.

1. Need a DL AMI or custom AMI which has NVIDIA driver installed. Use AWS DL AMI.
2. Make sure AWS batch has EC2 p2/p3 instances in the compute environment configuration.
3. Metaflow does not look after GPU driver and library, but `metaflow configure aws` allows which docker image to use. Specify the docker image (ECR repository) which has NVIDIA driver and CUDA are installed. Use AWS Deep Learning Container.
4. Use @Batch and specif GPU attribute.

Details in the Github issue.